# Example of bison grammar for function declaration and usage

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, context-free-grammar, bisonc++

Can somebody give an example of bison grammar for function declaration and function usage such that parser produces an error if number of arguments in declaration and usage vary?

Comment: I'm afraid such decision is not context-free so cannot be decided by a context-free grammar.

Comment: Hi Jiri. Could you please elaborate a bit? From your answer I'm assuming that I'll have to check for such a condition in the codegen step then

Comment: Expanded into a full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such decision cannot be done by a context-free grammar, i.e. it is impossible to write it into a "pure" grammar used by Bison ("pure" meaning a grammar containing just rules with symbols and no embedded actions).

To achieve your task, you'll need to add [semantic actions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Semantic-Actions) to appropriate rules of your grammar that use a [symbol table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table) to communicate the information about number of function's argument between the declaration and use of that function (in declaration rule, you add entry to the symbol table, and in function use rule you check the number of arguments).

Traditionally, such checks are considered part of semantic analysis and are often done in a separate step following the syntax analysis (parsing).